# Filter on specific subject but only unique / first instance

Tags: vba, microsoft-outlook-2013, email-filter, rules

I have an Outlook rule that is triggered by any incoming emails with the word "crisis" in the subject.  The problem is that it is triggered by any corresponding replies in our ticketing system (meaning there is no RE: or any other way to determine that it is a reply).  So after I get a "crisis" email, which might have a subject like the following, I will without a doubt get 10-20 more with the exact same subject in the next few days as people discuss the ticket.

`System 2015.123.123134 C2315 CRISIS`

I have tried at length and there is *no* way with a standard outlook rule to differentiate between the original message and replies based on subject or body.

Can I do this with VBA somehow? Would I have to store a log of the subjects in order to accomplish this?  Any other ideas?

Comment: I actually thought I was on SO.  Hopefully someone here has ideas anyway.

Comment: I essentially write logs for this kind of thing and check them for new mails, using VBA.  (I'd post the code but it's all tied up in my other code.)   Another VBA approach I haven't tried might be to use MailItem.ConversationID to see if the incoming mail belongs to a conversation you already have mails from.

Comment: You can try to analyze message headers for first message and for replies. Maybe you can additional headers in replies?

Comment: @thims they aren't replies. They are notifications of replies to a ticketing system

Comment: I understand, but maybe your ticketing system stamps initial support request or "replies" with some x-header or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with.  Basically it's a VBA that checks a specific folder to see if there are any emails with subjects that match the newly received email.  If there are, it does nothing.  If there are no matches, then it copies it to the folder and sends a new email with a unique subject that I can then apply another rule to.

```
Sub HSAlertRule(newMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim EntryID As String
    Dim StoreID As Variant
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim aType As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Status As String
    Static targetAccount As String
    targetAccount = "me@myemail.com"


    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    EntryID = newMail.EntryID
    StoreID = newMail.Parent.StoreID

    Set mi = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(EntryID, StoreID)

    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim objFolder, objInbox, objAlerts, objFirst As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set objFirst = objNS.Folders.GetFirst
    Set objInbox = objNS.Folders(targetAccount).Folders("Inbox")
    Set objAlerts = objInbox.Folders("Alerts")

    For Each oMail In objFolder.Items
        If oMail.subject = mi.subject Then
            found = True
        End If
    Next

    If found Then
        'ignore
        found = False
    Else
        SendMessage()
        'separate rule on this message for desktop alerts, etc.
        mi.Move objFolder
    End If
    Set mi = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: @thims are you going to attempt to be helpful and explain why?

Comment: Not here. Offtopic on SU.

Comment: Then where?  It was apparently on-topic enough to berate me.

Comment: Ok, try to run your script on a folder with, say, 10000 items and see for yourself. Now imagine this script'd be run for each incoming message.

Comment: So can you recommend an alternate way of iterating over the messages or are you just saying it's a bad idea in general?

Comment: In general, never iterate through COM objects. Use folder's GetTable().

Comment: There it is! A useful comment.  I knew you could do it!  I'll look into GetTable! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860692.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396